# How I can "foreach" into children of div with XPATH in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I don't know how to iterate of each children of my div in puppeteer. I have try a lot of things like page.evaluate but it's not working like I want.

I want to iterate on each children and make checks/actions, but with page.evaluate (I don't know how really it's work) it's not working like this.

```
    const example = await page.evaluate(element => {
        console.log(element)
        return element.textContent;
    }, (await page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/fieldset/div'))[0]);
    console.log(example)
```

`console.log(element)` returning nothing and in the arrow function I can't make checks/actions because it's working "one time".. I home you will understand me, I'm a beginnerwith puppeteer.

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the type of your elements or any other attributes such as a class, id, or name? Don't forgot you can uses typical DOM selections functions, such as document.getelementbyid. Also check out https://cheerio.js.org/. I sometimes dump the HTML into cheerio and parse using their functions. Very nice for getting more fine grain results.